# laptop does not start up

Tags: startup

Operating System: Linux
I am using my notebook( HP product model : 15d011TU) nearly 14 months without any problem which came with windows 8 . recently I installed Linux based os Ubuntu .... Now the problem starts ... Sometimes it freezes n sometimes hang on... N the worst part was last night I turned it off n could not turn it on again!!!!! WHEN I PUSH POWER BUTTON , ONLY THE WIFI LIGHT ( ORANGE COLOUR) TURNING ON FOR 10 SEC THEN GONE...!,,!!!!

I tried several tricked which I found here but still its not working.
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a hardware problem to be honest. Regardless of any software issue you may have the key here is "I turned it off and could not turn it on again!".

Make sure you check that your power cord is connected securely to the laptop and the individual cables of the power cord are not loose. Laptop power cords often are in multiple segments and sometimes they come loose without you knowing about it. If your laptop has been running a long time and not charging then it would not be able to turn on.

If you can clearly see it boot but it doesnt go into the login screen then you may have a problem with your Linux install. Typically that can be fixed just by reinstalling or if you have a lot of files you cant lose doing something else.

If it is not either of those and you are not getting any power even with the cord attached then you likely have a hardware problem that may need to be addressed by the manufacturer. Call them up and see what they think. Depending on your warranty length you may be able to get it fixed.